# How to Customize a Contact Form Plugin as per Requirement

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming, contact-form

I am new to wordpress. i have created a wordpress theme (for website development) where i have developed a contact page . In  Contact Page i want to add contact form which should be look like this:

[Contact Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfuGi.jpg)

I have tried to achieve this target by using Cform2 plugin and contact form 7 plugin but i failed to achieve my target .

Please help me how i can customize a contact form plugin as per requirnment. On which files i need to make changes, currently i have cform2 , contact form 7 plugin in my wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to make your own html and css for contact page. And then use the contact form 7 and replace the your input field by contact form 7 input field and put class as you used in html. `[text* name class:your_class]` 
In this way you can achieve your required answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply. could you please provide me some working example for above mentioned method ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my html structure of my contact form.

```
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 form-group contact-group">
            <span>Name</span>
            [text* your-name class:form-control]
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 form-group contact-group">
          <span>Email</span>
            [email* your-email class:form-control]
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 form-group message-cont">
          <span>Message</span>
             [textarea your-message class:form-control]
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
          [submit class:submit-btn "Submit"]
          </div>
      </div>
```

You can change div structure and class are per your requirement and also you have to add css as required.

Comment: thanx for reply . i am a bit confused . i want to add captcha and on which file i need to add css for this form ?

Comment: You can use captcha plugins for this. like https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-simple-recaptcha/ or other.

Comment: "Custom Contact Forms is experiencing issues.There is an issue with synchronizing data. Please try the following:
1. Go to Settings > Permalinks and click "Save Changes". This flushes your permalinks. If this fixes your problem, you are good to go!
Deactivate all other plugins and activate the TwentySixteen theme. If this fixes the problem, there is a plugin or theme conflict. Please report on Github or the support forums.                                                                               If neither of these things fix your problem, please report on Github or the support forums."

Comment: after your suggestions i am facing above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Contact Form 7, the area where the html of contact form 7 is showing you can use your own ids,and classes and can change the css in your own style sheet.